# Pandas dataframe growing exponentially

Tags: python, pandas

I have time series data stored in a series of EXCEL files, whose names are stored in a list.  The times are identical in each file and I would like to extract some of the columns from each file and store them in a `Pandas DataFrame`.  The date is in column A of the XL file and the data items are in columns B and C.  The code stub is

```
for x in a_list:
        
    # Create temporary dataframe
        
    tmp_df = pd.read_excel(x, sheet_name="Sheet1", header=None, names=["", x + "_1", x + "_2"], 
                           index_col=0, usecols=[0, 1, 2], nrows=444)

    # Merge with existing dataframe

    if df.empty:
        df = tmp_df
    else:
        df = df.join(tmp_df)
            
    df.drop_duplicates()
```

The first pass gives a dataframe with shape (444,2), the second (536, 4), the third (1440, 6), the fourth (10440, 8) etc. until the script stops running because of a memory error.  The column count is growing as expected but I don't understand why the row count grows rapidly when we read the same 444 dates each time.  I have tried using `df.merge` instead of `dj.join` but the result is the same.  I added `df.drop_duplicates` based on similar StackOverflow posts but that had no effect.  Would appreciate any suggestions - thanks in advance!

Update:
It turned out that the problem was nothing to do with the concatentation/joining method but my using the wrong number of rows when reading from EXCEL.  I read too many so the indices were not the same, as I had assumed.  Implemented @Corralien's first solution (neater than mine) and everything good

Comment: I think there is different indices, try `df.join(tmp_df)` change to `df.join(tmp_df.reset_index(drop=True))`

Comment: Hi @jezrael.  Indices are identical but tried your suggestion anyway and got this error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
data = []
for x in a_list:     
    df = pd.read_excel(x, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None,
                       names=['', x + '_1', x + '_2'], 
                       index_col=0, usecols=[0, 1, 2], nrows=444)
    data.append(df)

df = pd.concat(data)  # or pd.concat(data, axis=1)
```

**Update**

Try:

```
data = []
for x in a_list:     
    df = pd.read_excel(x, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None,
                       usecols=[0, 1, 2], nrows=444)
    data.append(df)

df = pd.concat(data).set_index(0).rename_axis(None)
```

Comment: Hi @Corralien  Tried your solution and got this error message `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` when the `df = pd.concat(data)` statement was executed.  I got the same message when I tried `df = pd.conat(df, tmp_df)`

Comment: Remove `index_col=0` then `concat`. Finally remove duplicates. I don't understand why you change the column names? Do the columns are not the same between each dataframe.

Comment: Hi Corralien I want to index the df using the date stored in column 0 of the XL hence `index_col=0` .  I rename the column names because there are multiple sheets with different names (representing different things) but with the same column names

Comment: You can set index after the concat. If you use `x + '_1'`, you will never have the same column names on all dataframe,

Comment: The updated answer gives this error `KeyError: 'None of [0] are in the columns'`